# Laravel Blade Compiler

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have problem with:

```
Blade::compileString()
```

I have article view:

```
{!! Blade::compileString($article->content) !!}
```

My **$article->content** contain:

```
<p>Test</p>
<p>{{ module('contact') }}</p>
```

And I don't know why blade compiling it to:

[source screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7LXE.png)

Why module() function is not executing?

Comment: post your complete code

Answer (score 0):

Function calls are never compiled.

Let's say your view shows the current time and you'd call `{{ date('H:i:s') }}` in order to do that. When compiling, that will change to a certain timestamp, say 12:34:56. Now everytime an user refreshes the page, even hours later, the time won't change anymore until the view is next compiled, which would have the undesired effect of basically freezing your entire page.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hmm, I understand, so what is the best way to allow user to use function dynamically?

Comment: What I would do is store the article content in the database un-compiled, exactly like it is. And then compile it at runtime, each time you display it.